# Razor View Without Layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, layout, razor

How come when I have `Layout = null;` in my view - it still pulls in the default layout?!

Is there some trick to stop it doing that?

Here is my view without layout:

```
@{
    Layout = "";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
    @{Html.RenderAction("Head", "Header");}
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        Home
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the rendered output!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    header
</body>
</html>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        Home
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you see the word `null` in the rendered page?

Comment: Where are you setting the default layout?

Comment: Do you have a _viewstart.cshtml in this directory? I had the same problem you're having when I tried using _viewstart. Then I renamed it _mydefaultview, moved it to the views/shared directory, and switched to specifying no view in cshtml files where I don't want it, and specifying _mydefaultview for the rest. Don't know why this was necessary, but it worked.

Comment: please set that as an answer and i'll mark it correct. this must be a bug in razor surely?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a bug, _viewstarts are intended not to be overwritten, or if we did something wrong. I'd like to know too.

Comment: Logic for determining if a View should use a layout or not should NOT be in the layout.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Do you have a `_ViewStart.cshtml` in this directory? I had the same problem you're having when I tried using _ViewStart. Then I renamed it _mydefaultview, moved it to the `Views/Shared` directory, and switched to specifying no view in cshtml files where I don't want it, and specifying _mydefaultview for the rest. Don't know why this was necessary, but it worked.

Comment: That sounds weird.  The `_ViewStart` should run before the code in the view, so this issue shouldn't happen.  Do you have anything unusual in your _ViewStart?

Comment: @SLaks♦ I made a _viewstart that just contains "Hello World" to test, and the Hello World still shows up even if I specify Layout = null. However, if I specify _mydefaultview as the layout then that shows up too. The "hello world" is showing up inbetween tags where I have @RenderBody() in _mydefaultview.

Comment: You're misuderstanding `_ViewStart`.  See my answer.

Answer (score 212):

I think this:

```
@{
    Layout = "";
 }
```

is not the same as this:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
 }
```

I use the second and it's working, no _ViewStart included.

Comment: How is this not the correct answer for this question?

Comment: The latter worked for me and was the first thing that came to mind.

Comment: @Pinski probably because it was added 2 years later. :)

Answer (score 39):

You (and KMulligan) are misunderstanding `_ViewStart` pages.

`_ViewStart` will *always* execute, before your page starts.
It is intended to be used to initialize properties (such as `Layout`); it generally should not contain markup.  (Since there is no way to override it).

The correct pattern is to make a separate layout page which calls `RenderBody`, and set the `Layout` property to point to this page in `_ViewStart`.

You can then change `Layout` in your content pages, and the changes will take effect.

Comment: well my `_Layout.cshtml` contains all the basic designs. and `_ViewStart.cshtml` calls the `_Layout.cshtml`. each module of my App has their own layout page but those layout uses the main `_Layout.cshtml`. as the mvc app starts from the viewstart, I guess my only solution was to comment everything inside viewstart. and that doesn't cause any extra problems because other pages were already using `_Layout.cshtml`. pretty simple.

Answer (score 29):

I think it's better work with individual "views", Im trying to move from PHP to MVC4, its really hard but im on the right way...

Answering your question, if you'll work individual pages, just edit the _ViewStart.cshtml

```
@{
  Layout = null;
}
```

Another tip if you're getting some issues with CSS path.

Put "../" before of the URL.

These were the 2 problems that I got today, and I resolved them in that way.

Answer (score 25):

**Logic** for determining if a View should use a layout or not should NOT be in the `_viewStart` nor the `View`.  Setting a default in `_viewStart` is fine, but adding any layout logic in the view/viewstart prevents that view from being used anywhere else (with or without layout).

Your Controller Action should:

```
return PartialView()
```

By putting this type of logic in the View you breaking the [Single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) rule in M (data), V (visual), C  (logic).

Comment: This is contrary to what Scott Gu says here http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts . `we could write code within our _ViewStart.cshtml file to programmatically set the Layout property for each View ... we could vary the Layout template that we use depending on what type of device is accessing the site – and have a phone or tablet optimized layout for those devices` He's clearly promoting _viewstart as a place to use logic to switch layouts (also mentions controllers and action filters). So it's more a matter of preference than absolutes re: where to switch layouts.

Comment: My preference is to stick to designs patterns.  You may throw database access in your view, it's also bad practice or "a matter of preference".

Comment: That's a fairly hyperbolic response as is the statement "adding any layout logic in the view/viewstart prevents that view from being used anywhere else ". It depends entirely upon the application in question. There are countless examples in which a given view has no dependency on it's layout (master) file. The master is simply there for some branding or nav and all we might want to do is switch between a mobile and desktop layout of that (fluid layouts aside). One could even argue that you actually break SRP by making a controller also responsible for switching layouts in this context .

Comment: I don't see your point of view on your last statement.  The view is presentation of data.  Any logic in that view means it cannot be used else where and prevents testing of that logic which would normally happen in the controller.  The controller has logic already built into MVC ([IsAjaxRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajaxrequestextensions.isajaxrequest%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) or [ChildActionOnly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.childactiononlyattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)) to determine the correct presentation.

Comment: That presentation may or may not (JSON/XML) not even be Html rendered by a View Engine, so why place logic that determines what needs to be displayed in multiple places (controller, viewstart, and view) when a the controller (the only place that can determine all the types of presentations) can unify the logic and create more maintainable and testable code.

Comment: Here we are talking about _ViewStart which are ViewResult specific. So `.. may or may not (JSON/XML) not even be Html rendered by a View Engine` has no bearing. A _layout is just a view that wraps a view. (They don't all start with `<!DOCTYPE html>`). So it may be perfectly feasible to have _ViewStart switching _layouts on and off according to some property i.e. day of week. In a given context, it could break SRP to have ControllerA for a ViewA making some determination about which _layout page to inject ViewA into as that's beyond it's SRP scope. It exists only to support ViewA<>ViewModelA.

Comment: What happens if you now add another _layout or turn all layouts off on Tuesday? You have to change ControllerA for ViewA, and all the other view controllers to account for this. That breaks SRP. ControllerA should only change according to the needs of ViewA <> ViewModelA. Much better re: SRP to have a single _layout switcher i.e. _ViewStartPage making this determination in a single DRY place. So i disagree that you should never put this code in ViewStarts (thats what they are for) and I can see how it could actually break SRP not to do it this way (again, all depending on app)

Answer (score 13):

Use:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
 }
```

to get rid of the layout specified in _ViewStart.

Answer (score 4):

**Procedure 1 : Control Layouts rendering by using _ViewStart file in the root directory of the Views folder**

This method is the simplest way for beginners to control Layouts rendering in your ASP.NET MVC application. We can identify the controller and render the Layouts as par controller, to do this we can write our code in _ViewStart file in the root directory of the Views folder. Following is an example shows how it can be done.

```
 @{
 var controller = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString();
 string cLayout = "";
 if (controller == "Webmaster") {
 cLayout = "~/Views/Shared/_WebmasterLayout.cshtml";
 }
 else {
 cLayout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }
 Layout = cLayout;
 }
```

**Procedure 2 : Set Layout by Returning from ActionResult**

One the the great feature of ASP.NET MVC is that, we can override the default layout rendering by returning the layout from the ActionResult. So, this is also a way to render different Layout in your ASP.NET MVC application. Following code sample show how it can be done.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
 SampleModel model = new SampleModel();
 //Any Logic
 return View("Index", "_WebmasterLayout", model);
}
```

**Procedure 3 : View - wise Layout (By defining Layout within each view on the top)**

ASP.NET MVC provides us such a great feature & faxibility to override the default layout rendering by defining the layout on the view. To implement this we can write our code in following manner in each View.

```
@{
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_WebmasterLayout.cshtml";
}
```

**Procedure 4 : Placing _ViewStart file in each of the directories**

This is a very useful way to set different Layouts for each Controller in your ASP.NET MVC application. If we want to set default Layout for each directories than we can do this by putting _ViewStart file in each of the directories with the required Layout information as shown below:

```
@{
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_WebmasterLayout.cshtml";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to display the login page without the layout and this works pretty good for me.(this is the _ViewStart.cshtml file)
You need to set the ViewBag.Title in the Controller.

```
@{
    if (! (ViewContext.ViewBag.Title == "Login"))
    {
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";        
    } 
}
```

I know it's a little bit late but I hope this helps some body.

Answer (score 2):

Just create the view as a partial view so that no layout file is used.

Answer (score -1):

@{
 `viewbag.title="index"`
Layout = null;
}

Comment: add some explanation please

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65627207/edit) your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.