# how to switch ng-view to normal page

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-routing, ng-view

[image]

See image
=>Layout1 master page which include ng-view in that i used angular routing.

=>Layout2 login.cshml page when I tried to call login page
      http://localhost:1395/admin/home/Login

this login page included in ng-view which i donot want
its total different page  Login.cshtml

I called this page like

```
   <a href="admin/home/login">Log out</a>
```

when I tried url directly in address bar like http://localhost:1395/admin/home/Login
it works fine see image

[image]

but i tried from master panel to login page it shows wrong see first image

example code

master.cshtml

```
  <html>
 <body>
 <div>Layout 1</div>
 <div ng-view></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

contact.html

```
 <div ng-controller="contactcontroller">
 Contact Page
 </div>
```

help.html

```
 <div ng-controller="helpcontroller">
 Help Page
</div>
```

routing code

```
      var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
      app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
   .when("/admin/home/contact", {
    templateUrl : "contact.html",
    controller: "contactcontroller"
  })
   .when("/admin/home/help", {
    templateUrl : "help.html",
    controller:   "helpcontroller"
 })    
});
```

Login.cshtml

```
 <html>
  <body>
  <div>Layout 2</div>
  ///Login code
</body>
</html>
```

when I call this url admin/home/help and admin/home/contact pages included in ng-view  but when I call admin/home/login i donot want this include in ng-view it is separate header and footer . I want call as separate page

Thanks in advance

Comment: please try to clarify, provide additianal info a nd code samples. There's no clue how your application works and what you expect it to do.

Comment: thanks for reply @ kvetis  please check sample code for reference. I want switch from page which included ng-view to normal page which not included ng-view

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to understand this, but I'll take a shot at answering the question.

Your problem is probably *unrelated to angularjs*, what it seems to me is, that you're probably using ASP.NET MVC and your Login action is rendered inside the master layout. Basically you need to render the page without the template. See this question and answers there: [Razor View Without Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613626/razor-view-without-layout)

I will also point out that angular is used for single page applications and it is hard to mix angular and ASP.NET MVC routing. You should probably decide which routing you will use. Sure, you can use .NET and initialize angular in every page, but I don't recommend this. If you can, build all your pages in angular and then then use [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api%20%22ASP.NET%20Web%20API) as a back-end.

Also you don't need to use `ng-controller` attribute when you use routing and specify controller.