# Populate Modelpopup with different page(View) in Mvc using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, modalpopup

I am trying to load a view(not a partial view) inside a Model popup in mvc
I have 2 .cshtml pages that is View's
Modelpopup.cshtml and
loadmodal.cshtml

Modelpopup code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    var $modal = $('#load_popup_modal_show_id');
    $('#click_to_load_modal_popup').on('click', function () {

         $modal.load("@Url.Action("Loadmodel", "ToolManager")", function() {
             $modal.modal('show');
         });   

    });

});
```

Open Popup Modal

loadmodal code

```
<div id="load_popup_modal_contant" class="" role="dialog">

<div class="modal-dialog modal-md">



    <form role="form" class="form-inline" role="form" id="form_load_content_id">

        <!-- Start: Modal content-->

        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">

                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

                <h4 class="modal-title">Show Popup Title Here</h4>

            </div>

            <div id="validation-error"></div>

            <div class="cl"></div>

            <div class="modal-body">

                <h3> Modal Popup content Here</h3>

            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">



                <input name="submit_popup" id="submit_popup" type="button" value="SUBMIT" class="btn btn-primary" />

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

</div>
```

I want to load loadmodal.cshtml into a popup how can i do this using above code or by any other way, i do not want to use partial view

my controller code

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Modelpopup()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult loadmodal()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: What problem are you facing with this code? If you dont't want a partial view then set  Layout = null in loadmodal.cshtml file. So the layout page be ignored for that view

Comment: popup is not showing up..screen gets stuck...

Comment: i want to do this kind of stuff ..this link code is in php i want to it in mvc http://www.discussdesk.com/online-demo/bootstrap-modal-popup

Comment: I guess, your loadmodal.cshtml file has a reference to layout page as well. 
@{
    Layout = null;
 }
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613626/razor-view-without-layout

Comment: No its not having layout

Comment: If you are getting any error in the browser console window, share that as well.

Comment: Or try one thing: In your LoadModal Action method try replacing return View() with return PartialView(); Because even if you don't specify the Layout page in the .cshtml file it picks up from _viewstart file.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/bpCQW6NoRAzgOIqvIn2V?p=preview

Comment: Thankyou for your reply...what if  this div is in another page "<div class="modal" id="modalDiv">" and i want to call  id="modalDiv" from dirrerentpage how can i do this

Comment: @Chethan sir this model is decleared in same page..my requirement is...mu model is decleared on another page how to call that

Comment: updated my plnkr. check the answer

Answer (score 2):

with reference to your comments, I have updated the [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/bpCQW6NoRAzgOIqvIn2V?p=preview).
you will have to declare the modal inside the load success function. Because the div "#load_popup_modal_show_id" will be available after the ajax call is successful. (at least for the first time).

```
$(document).ready(function () {        
    $('#click_to_load_modal_popup').on('click', function () {
         $modal.load("@Url.Action("Loadmodel", "ToolManager")", function() {
         var $modal = $('#load_popup_modal_show_id');                 
         $modal.modal('show');
         });   
     });
 });
```

Comment: This helped me out today. Thank you!